# Yii2 and Dropzone - How do I save filenames with path to database?

Tags: yii2, dropzone

I am using Yii2 and also Dropzone (from https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone) and I have placed the control on a Form.

Now I am facing difficulty in getiing the file names of the uploaded files.

Can you help me on how do I check for array of uploaded files so that I can save that array to a filed in database.

*** Edit *******

**What I am doing?** 
I have a Form with different Controls and have added the dropzone control(widget) to get images from the form submitter.

**Whats the issue?**
Now the dropzone control is working fine. As soon as images are added to it it uploads the images to the designated folder.

But real issue comes when I need to save the Form Data with Url of Images. I am getting the form data without any isseue but no $_FILES is available as files have already uploaded. So how do I get their name while saving form data.

Comment: Please give more detail and what you are doing ?

Comment: Can you send your view, model and controller example?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get filenames of uploaded files using `yii\web\UploadedFile` class.

See this simple example upload action,

```
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new UploadForm();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');

        if ($model->upload()) { // You should implement your own upload method 
            // file is uploaded successfully
            return;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

For more clarification check this out http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html